# Refusal of a .dj (Djibouti) domain because of inappropriate content

Tags: domains, domain-registration, content, top-level-domains

I am planning a website containing nudity and pornographic material on a .dj domain.
In the terms and conditions (http://www.dj/eterms.htm) for the registration of a .dj domain it says under Article 5, Section 2:

> Pornographic, damaging, insulting, defamatory, blasphemous, sacrilegious **names**, etc. will be refused.

The actual domain name I want to register is completely neutral. A fictional but very short name.
Just the **content** will be pornographic.

I have talked to the domain company I usually register domains with and they said, pornographic content on a fictional .dj domain is possible but they strongly advice against that because the registrar can cancel the contract at every time in the future. For example if a visitor reports the website to the .dj officials.

Are they correct? Is it safe to have pornographic content on a .dj domain? Do you know any case of a closing of a domain name in the past (except with FBI/CIA involvement because of illegal content)?

Comment: I wouldn't risk it, Djibouti is an islamic country (so pornography is banned). 

Porn in content but not in name is really splitting hairs and I'd say it goes against the spirit of their terms. I'd expect the domain to be seized/cancelled if was noticed.

Answer (score 1):

For pornographic content you can use a .XXX domains which only for the adult content website. And there will be NO refusal to the service or banning of the website

Comment: In my opinion, there is literally no advantage in having .xxx domain and I believe that the only reason why anyone made that TLD was to more easily block the inappropriate content.

Comment: @Jeyekomon There might be an advantage over a country domain where the registrar might take the domain back when it contains objectionable material.  There may be no advantage compared to a .com though